# select query to make one column as key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

I need the array as (2) from a single query
can anyone help ?

```
1.  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crop_id] => 3
            [crop_name] => Barley
        )

2. Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Barley] => 3
        ) 

)
```

Comment: This is easy to do when you're looping over the results. Just create an array entry whose key is one column and the value is the other. `$array[$row['crop_name']] = $row['crop_id'];`

Comment: For this, you should have to write your own logic after getting the records from the table.

Comment: CAN I GET THIS FROM MYSQL ONLY

Comment: Yes you can write down a stored procedure with two SELECT statements concatenated using UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about query but you can do that simply using **array_map()**

```
$array[] = array('crop_id' => 3, 'crop_name' => "Barley");

$result = array_map("myfunction",$array);
print_r($result);

function myfunction($v)
{
    $data = [];
    $data[$v['crop_name']] = $v['crop_id'];
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have stored your data in array named as crop_data like

$crop_data[0][crop_id]=3; 
$crop_data[0][crop_name]='Barley';
....

$crop_data[n][crop_id]=187;
$crop_data[n][crop_name]='Wheat'

Try this code:

```
$new_crop_result=array()
foreach($crop_data as $key=>$record)
{
  $new_crop_result[$key][$record[crop_name]]=$record[crop_id];
}
```